# Is this charge pump analysis correct?

Tags: capacitor, cmos, charge

Assume switch on resistance is 0. Also assume that phi1 and phi2 are non overlapping clock signals and that the initial condition of all caps is 0V.

[image]

My final answer suggests that Vout/Vin is 2 only if Cout is much lower than Cf. Seems a little strange, since you would expect Cout to be large enough to sustain the load current applied at Vout.

**Have I done something wrong?** Most analysis online suggest that Cf transfer all of it's charge to Cout during phi2 but they don't mention anything about the capacitor sizing or charge sharing.

UPDATE:
As per Horror Vacui's comment, I have re-calculated in steady-state and it now makes sense!
[image]

Comment: You should calculate for steady-state, i.e. when C_out already has a charge of Q_out=C_out*V_out in it.

Comment: @HorrorVacui Very good point, completely missed that I was calculating at initial period only. It makes sense now. Thanks